# Alternatives to exposing a template parameter from a composed class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm modifying a class by adding a data-member that is templated. The code will invariably be using a default template type for the template parameter in all invocations, except for one place. Partially motivated by this, and partially due to a a desire/whim, I do not want to add a template parameter to the class as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Der>
class A : private Der {
    public:
    int get() { return Der::get_(); }
};

class B {
    protected:
    int get_() { return 20; }
};

class C {
    protected:
    int get_() { return 30; }
};

using Default = B;

template <class T = Default>
class User {
    public:
    User() {}

    A<T>& getMember() { return m_; }

    private:
    A<T> m_; // This is what I am adding, and exposing param T.
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    User h;
    std::cout<<h.getMember().get()<<std::endl;
}
```

One solution that I could think of is the use of a sum-type, but this introduces some exception handling code:

```
class User {
    public:
    User() : m_(A<Default>()) {}

    template <typename T>
    User(const T& in) : m_(in) {}

    template <typename T>
    A<T>& getMember() { return std::get<A<T>>(m_); }

    private:
    std::variant<A<B>, A<C>> m_;
};
```

I'm looking for:

- A name for what I am trying to do, if it exists.
- Ways in which I can accomplish what I desire.

Comment: "The code will invariably be using a default template type for the template parameter in all invocations, except for one place."  Define two classes?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, as I don't find the virtual function call completely satisfactory, but, as progress, another option I can share is type-erasure using an inner base class.

Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class User {
    public:
    template <class T>
    User(T&&) : m_(new Internal<T>()) {}

    int doOnMember() { return m_->doOnMember(); }

    private:
    class InternalBase {
        public:
        virtual int doOnMember() = 0;
    };

    template <typename T>
    class Internal : public InternalBase {
        public:
        Internal() {} 
        int doOnMember() { return m_.get(); }

        private:
        A<T> m_;
    };

    private:
    std::shared_ptr<InternalBase> m_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    User h(B{});
    std::cout<<h.doOnMember()<<std::endl;
    User h1(C{});
    std::cout<<h1.doOnMember()<<std::endl;
}
```